# Add file template to every existing class - Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have just created a file template. That we are in one line I talk about [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html)

Unfortunately I was a bit late with it and have already more than 90 classes.

I would be very happy if my changes in template file `File Header.java` would add/apply to all my implementations at once. Is that somehow possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to apply changed file template to already created files.

You can run [Find and Replace in Path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html) or [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/search-templates.html) to add the text to existing files.